# how to check if the tag contains sepcfic string in xslt

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I am using `XSLT` with `C#`.

My input tag is in the format like

```
<td>....</td>
<td>uma</td>
```

I need to convert *`td`* to *`entry`* tag and check if it contains the following sequence `...`
so my output will be as follow.

```
 <entry></entry>
<entry>uma</entry>
```

How to check if the tag contains only `...` and replace with empty.
Tag always contains `...`, it is static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td">
        <entry>
            <xsl:if test=". != '...'">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this condition using

```
td[text() = '...']
```